# How can I parse a date in Rails without a month or a day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, internationalization

I need to parse a date in Rails from a JSON string that could possibly be provided without a month or day, and return it in ISO8601 format. If a day is not provided, then I need to return the first of the month of the year, and if a month is not provided, the first of the year.

Simply running `DateTime.parse(response['date']).utc.iso8601` throws an `ArgumentError` when the month or day is missing, such as `DateTime.parse('2001')`.

DateTime handles my exact conditions beautifully with `DateTime.new` with optional integer parameters, but how can I best handle this when parsing a string?

I have to keep i18n in mind when doing this, so while I could store three diferent formatted string args for `strptime` for each locale, that seems hacky. If that is indeed the best way to handle this, I'd love an explanation.

Comment: Just to be clear, the string '2001' should convert to a date object representing 1 Jan 2001?  What would an example of a date with a month, but without the day, look like?

Comment: `2001-05` should convert to 1 May 2001